# Using regex, how can I check if a certain string is at the start of a sentence?

Tags: java, regex

How can I check if a specific string is at the start of a sentence using regex? Here are my examples.

The flag I want to search for is "CEO"

If the string starts with CEO, then it will be blocked, but it will be accepted if found anywhere else in the word.

```
"CEO Hello": blocked
"CEOHello": blocked
"HelloCEO": accepted
"Hello CEO": accepted
```

CASE does not matter.

Edit: Thanks guys, was missing the "^" for the start of the String.

Comment: Have you tried anything? The `Pattern` class javadoc has you covered.

Comment: I have tried but it counts for the whole string and not just the beginning

Comment: **The [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class javadoc has you covered.**

Comment: `^` is used as beginning of the line

Comment: Did you know that the String class has a startsWith() method?

Comment: Add your code to the post.

Comment: Yes I'm aware I can use the String class, but I need to be using regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean isBlocked = "your string".matches("^CEO.*");
```